# Why the original source code is showing in the source using webpack? And how to disable it?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using Facebook's 'create-react-app' template to create my project, after I deployed it to server, I find out that I can view the source code via:

`Chrome > Console > Sources > webpack://`

Is this possible to disable it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just checked my project. Can see the source code

Comment: can you provide the create-react-app version, webpack.prod config and may be the site url to check

Answer (score 1):

1. Eject your `create-react-app` by running `npm run eject`
2. Open `/config/webpack.config.prod.js`
3. Remove or comment out line 53 containing `devtool: 'source-map',`
4. Build, and deploy your app again

Ironically, the annotations inside of `/config/webpack.config.prod.js` admit generating sourcemaps in production "is slow but gives good results". I'm not sure what *good results* means but theres your fix.

Comment: I would say put GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in your .env file rather than edit the webpack config